# defining a struct and functions using a macro, how to stop multiple definitions

Tags: c

I'm trying to define a dynamic array struct along with some functions to accompany it using a macro

```
//dynArray.h
#define CUTILS_DEF_DYNARRAY(TYPE, NAME)\
    typedef struct NAME{\
        TYPE *data;
        size_t size, capacity;
    } NAME;\
    //define functions here, e.g.
    int NAME##Init(NAME *arr, size_t size){\
        //code here
    }\
```

my issue happens when i define a dynamic array in a header, in this case using it to define an array of a string struct

```
//str.h
#include "dynArray.h"
//define struct here
CUTILS_DEF_DYNARRAY(cutilsString, cutilsStringArr);
```

The string header is included in `file.h`, and this causes conflict as the compiler tells me that there are multiple function definitions for the string array functions. Here is an example of one of the errors I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: out/file.o: in function `cutilsByteStreamArrInit':
file.c:(.text+0x290): multiple definition of `cutilsByteStreamArrInit'; out/bytestream.o:bytestream.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

All of my headers have proper include guards, and the macro to define the string functions is used once and only once in the string header. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You must be calling the macro several times with the same parameters.  But you have not included a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  so we cannot make a diagnostic.

Comment: I really was not, I did a search on the entire directory for the macro definition, and it was only there once per type. However Kamil Cuk's explanation is the reason behind this, it was due to the header being included multiple times which I guess is the same in a way as calling the macro multiple times.

Comment: Nope, it's including the header in different modules what makes the function to be defined several times (once per compilation unit where the header is used).  It's the linker that complaints because you have a function defined multiple times in the final executable.  If you don't mind having it several times, and you want it to be defined in the header, use the `inline` keyword for it to be inlined (in case it has a short body that justifies repeating the code) or use `static`,  so the visibility of it will reduce to the compilation unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the implementation into `.h` file and `.c` file.

```
// dynArray.h
#define CUTILS_DEF_DYNARRAY_H(TYPE, NAME) \
typedef struct NAME{ \
    TYPE *data; \
    size_t size, capacity; \
} NAME; \
/* declare (don't define) functions */ \
int NAME##Init(NAME *arr, size_t size); 

#define CUTILS_DEF_DYNARRAY_C(TYPE, NAME) \
int NAME##Init(NAME *arr, size_t size) { \
      /* something happens here */; \
      return 0; \
}
```

Then use it like:

```
// str.h
#include "dynArray.h"
CUTILS_DEF_DYNARRAY_H(cutilsString, cutilsStringArr)

// str.c
#include "str.h"
#include "dynArray.h"
CUTILS_DEF_DYNARRAY_C(cutilsString, cutilsStringArr)
```

and add `str.c` file to your compilation process.

Notes:

- Alternatively you can make all your exported symbols/variables/functions from the macro to be `static`.
- There is no `;` after the macro invocation.

> What am I doing wrong

You are declaring a symbol with external linkage in multiple transactions units. Ie. you have two `.c` files that are defining the same function `cutilsByteStreamArrInit` that is not `static`. And these two functions are linked together. You can only have a single definition of an externally visible symbol. Linker errors with multiple definitions error.

> how can I fix it?

Either create a separate `.c` file with all exported symbols definitions (what I suggest to do) or mark all symbols in the macro as `static`.